# Split only 3 letter StringBuilder

Tags: java, android

My `StringBuilder`:

```
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
```

And the output:

```
s.toString() = "ABCDEFG"
```

I just want the 3 letters of the beginning. Like "`ABC`".
What code do I need to use to do this?

Comment: _s.toString().substring(0,3);_

Comment: This is not an Android specific question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both String and StringBuilder have [`substring()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#substring%28int%29) methods. Simply call:

```
s.substring(0, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

use string.remove method

```
    string s = "ABCDEFG";
    s = s.Remove(3, 4)
```

Comment: I am unaware of `String#remove()` in [Java 1.5 or 1.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), could you provide a link to it's documentation?